# C# Console App To Print Data For Current Month

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable that has the month as the last column.  I need to print all the rows where the month = CurrentMonth.  So for example, this month would be March, next month would be April, etc.

Using the sample data below - how would I print the CN and the SS for all rows where SS = CurrentMonth?

And I want to print to the console...i.e. `Console.PrintLine();`

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
  DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
  dtData.Columns.Add("CN", typeof(string));
  dtData.Columns.Add("AN", typeof(string));
  dtData.Columns.Add("SN", typeof(string));
  dtData.Columns.Add("CE", typeof(string));
  dtData.Columns.Add("TSD", typeof(DateTime));
  dtData.Columns.Add("TSC", typeof(DateTime));
  dtData.Columns.Add("T1S", typeof(DateTime));
  dtData.Columns.Add("T1C", typeof(DateTime));
  dtData.Columns.Add("T2S", typeof(DateTime));
  dtData.Columns.Add("T2C", typeof(DateTime));
  dtData.Columns.Add("SS", typeof(string));

  dtData.Rows.Add("1111", "TestSN", "email", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "March");
  dtData.Rows.Add("2222", "TestSN1", "email1", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "July");
  dtData.Rows.Add("3333", "TestSN2", "email2", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "January");
  dtData.Rows.Add("4444", "TestSN3", "email3", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "April");
  dtData.Rows.Add("5555", "TestSN4", "email4", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "October");
  dtData.Rows.Add("6666", "TestSN5", "email5", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "December");
  dtData.Rows.Add("7777", "TestSN6", "email6", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "March");
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific.  What do you mean by "print data"?  Do you mean to a physical printer?  Have you made any attempt at printing this data yourself?  If so please add it to the question.

Comment: @Amy - sorry Console.PrintLine();

Comment: Have you tried iterating through the datatable rows, comparing last column value to current `DateTime` and printing the matching ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
foreach (DataRow r in dtData.Rows)
{
    if (r["SS"].ToString() == DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(r["CN"].ToString() + r["SS"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DataTable's Select method to select only the rows where the SS column is equal to this month.

```
var allRows = dt.Select($"SS='{DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}'");
            foreach(var r in allRows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{r["CN"].ToString()}, {r["SS"].ToString()}");
            }
```

Output:

```
1111, March
7777, March
```

Also, your code above does not compile. Looks like this line in your code should be removed:

```
dtData.Columns.Add("CE", typeof(string));
```

Comment: What does the $"SS=" mean?

Comment: $ is new way to say string.Format. The result is a data table select statement "Where SS = 'March'"

Answer (score 1):

what you need is a simple select query on your data:

```
    string expression = $"SS = '{DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM")}'";
    var filteredData = dtData.Select(expression);
    foreach(var item in filteredData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"CN: {item["CN"]}, SS: {item["SS"]}");
    }
```

by the way, your example has another problem which you forgot that your string columns are 4 and you are inserting 3 string in your rows:

```
    dtData.Rows.Add("1111", "TestSN",  "email",  "CE", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "March");
    dtData.Rows.Add("2222", "TestSN1", "email1", "CE", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "July");
    dtData.Rows.Add("3333", "TestSN2", "email2", "CE", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "January");
    dtData.Rows.Add("4444", "TestSN3", "email3", "CE", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "April");
    dtData.Rows.Add("5555", "TestSN4", "email4", "CE", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "October");
    dtData.Rows.Add("6666", "TestSN5", "email5", "CE", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "December");
    dtData.Rows.Add("7777", "TestSN6", "email6", "CE", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "March");
```